# find glib-2.0 library on ubuntu precise

Tags: ubuntu, glib

At this time, I try to use glib-2.0 with code:blocks but I can't find a shared glib on my ubuntu precise (12.04 LTS) somebody have an idea for that??
Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

I have found what I searched. 
use 'pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0' on an ubuntu terminal to find the directories of all the headers glib files to use. It gives to me: /usr/include/glib-2.0 and /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include . We add this two folders on code:blocks (settings ->compiler and debugger-> search directories). After do that, we have to specified to code:blocks which shared library to use with glib-2.0. On ubnutu it is  "/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.3" 
so go to code:blocks on: "setting->compiler and debuuger->link settings" and under "Link libraries" paste it.

Comment: Nice answer...I had for two days the same problem.